# Update Redux userData in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

> I am having an issue with **Redux** because i am very new in **React-native Redux.** i need to update my Redux data when i press the button.
>
> My SignIn Screen Code:
>
> ```
>  if (checkValid) {
>         updateState({isLoading: true});
>         try {
>           const res = await actions.login({
>             email,
>             password,
>           });
>         } catch (error) {
>           showError(error.msg);
>           updateState({isLoading: false});
>         }
>       }
> ```

> Redux Auth Code

```
import {LOGIN, SIGNUP} from '../../config/urls';
import {
  apiPost,
  clearUserData,
  setUserData,
  refreshUserData,
} from '../../utils/utils';
import {showError, showSuccess} from '../../utils/helperFunction';
import store from '../store';
import types from '../types';

const {dispatch} = store;

export const saveUserData = data => {
  dispatch({
    type: types.LOGIN,
    payload: data,
  });
};
export function login(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return apiPost(LOGIN, data)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.code == 400) {
          showError(res.message);
        } else if (res.code == 200) {
          showSuccess(res.message);
          setUserData(res.results).then(() => {
            resolve(res);
            saveUserData(res.results);
          });
          return;
        }
        resolve(res);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
export function signup(data) {
  return apiPost(SIGNUP, data);
}
export function logout() {
  dispatch({type: types.CLEAR_REDUX_STATE});
  showSuccess('User has been Logout successfully');
  clearUserData();
}

export function Update() {
  dispatch({type: types.UPDATE_REDUX_STATE});
  showSuccess('Data Updated successfully');
  refreshUserData();
}
```

> my Reducer code

```
import types from '../types';

const initial_state = {
  userData: {},
  is_verify: false,
  customer_first_time_login: false,
};

export default function (state = initial_state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOGIN:
      const data = action.payload;
      return {userData: data};
    case types.UPDATE_REDUX_STATE:
      const updateData = action.payload;
      return {userData: updateData};
    default:
      return {...state};
  }
}
```

> My utils
>
> ```
> import axios from 'axios';
> import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
> import store from '../redux/store';
> import types from '../redux/types';
> import {saveUserData} from '../redux/actions/auth';
> import {showError} from './helperFunction';
>
> const {dispatch, getState} = store;
>
> export async function getHeaders() {
>   let userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
>   if (userData) {
>     userData = JSON.parse(userData);
>     return {
>       authorization: `${userData.access_token}`,
>     };
>   }
>   return {};
> }
>
> export async function apiReq(
>   endPoint,
>   data,
>   method,
>   headers,
>   requestOptions = {},
> ) {
>   return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
>     const getTokenHeader = await getHeaders();
>     headers = {
>       ...getTokenHeader,
>       ...headers,
>     };
>
>     if (method === 'get' || method === 'delete') {
>       data = {
>         ...requestOptions,
>         ...data,
>         headers,
>       };
>     }
>     axios[method](endPoint, data, {headers})
>       .then(result => {
>         const {data} = result;
>         if (data.status === false) {
>           return rej(data);
>         }
>         return res(data);
>       })
>       .catch(error => {
>         if (error && error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
>           clearUserData();
>           dispatch({
>             type: types.CLEAR_REDUX_STATE,
>             payload: {},
>           });
>           dispatch({
>             type: types.NO_INTERNET,
>             payload: {internetConnection: true},
>           });
>         }
>         if (error && error.response && error.response.data) {
>           if (!error.response.data.message) {
>             return rej({
>               ...error.response.data,
>               msg: error.response.data.message || 'Network Error',
>             });
>           }
>           return rej(error.response.data);
>         } else {
>           return rej({message: 'Network Error', msg: 'Network Error'});
>         }
>         return rej(error);
>       });
>   });
> }
>
> export function apiPost(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
>   return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'post', headers);
> }
>
> export function apiDelete(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
>   return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'delete', headers);
> }
>
> export function apiGet(endPoint, data, headers = {}, requestOptions) {
>   return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'get', headers, requestOptions);
> }
>
> export function apiPut(endPoint, data, headers = {}) {
>   return apiReq(endPoint, data, 'put', headers);
> }
>
> export function setItem(key, data) {
>   data = JSON.stringify(data);
>   return AsyncStorage.setItem(key, data);
> }
>
> export function getItem(key) {
>   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>     AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(data => {
>       resolve(JSON.parse(data));
>     });
>   });
> }
>
> export function removeItem(key) {
>   return AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
> }
>
> export function clearAsyncStorate(key) {
>   return AsyncStorage.clear();
> }
>
> export function setUserData(data) {
>   data = JSON.stringify(data);
>   return AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', data);
> }
>
> export async function getUserData() {
>   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>     AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then(data => {
>       resolve(JSON.parse(data));
>     });
>   });
> }
>   
> export async function refreshUserData(endPoint, data = null, headers = {}) {
>   return axios
>     .get(endPoint)
>     .then(res => {
>       //comment below code to overcome the error
>       AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(user));
>       setUserData(res.data);
>       setUserData(res.data).then(() => {
>         saveUserData(res.data);
>       });
>       return res;
>     })
>     .catch(error => {
>       showError('Something went wrong');
>     });
> }
> export async function clearUserData() {
>   return AsyncStorage.removeItem('userData');
> }
> ```

> Now , i need to navigate the user to **FirstTimeLogin** screen when a **user SignIn Successfully** then a user can enter detail after entering detail user **navigate to Home screen**.
>
> i have made separate stack for every navigation like **AuthStack**, **MainStack** and **FristTimeLoginStack.** so my question is when a user signIn successfully it navigate automatically to **FirstTimeLogin** but then when a user enter details in **FirstTimeLogin** and press button then it will not navigate to **MainScreen** that means Redux state not update just like it was updated when a user SignIn
>
> Route Screen:
>
> ```
> export default function Routes() {
>   const userData = useSelector(state => state.auth.userData);
>   let showscreen;
>   
> if (userData != null && userData.access_token != null) {
>     if (userData.type == 'doctor') {
>       if (userData.doctor_detail == null) {
>         showscreen = [DoctorFTL(Stack)];
>       } else {
>         showscreen = [DoctorStack(Stack)];
>       }
>     }
>   } else {
>     showscreen = [AuthStack(Stack)];
>   }
>
>   return (
>     <NavigationContainer>
>       <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
>         {showscreen}
>       </Stack.Navigator>
>     </NavigationContainer>
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to look the documentation of Redux because you said you are very new with Redux.
[Redux Documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start)

and this link will help you to solve your problem.
[Solution link 1](https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-redux-persist-in-react-native-with-asyncstorage)
[Solution Link 2](https://enappd.com/blog/redux-in-react-native-app/92/)